# Issue converting object to int in Python for OLS regression

Tags: python, pandas, linear-regression

I'm trying to run a multiple linear regression in Python. One of my columns "member_total" is an object and I can't figure out how to convert it into an int. Right now, when I run the OLS model, this variable is interpreted as being categorical and thus I receive tons of coefficients for it.

[example]
[image]

I suspect the issue is because "member_total" is an object, but I can't figure out how to convert it.

I've tried:

```
member_total = int(sub.member_total)
```

and get this error:

```
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>
```

I've also tried:

```
sub = sub.astype(int)
```

and get this error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '27,908'
```

[df.member_total](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRl2A.png)

[dropping comma](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrA3n.png)

Comment: Could you please provide more details? What package are you using to fit the OLS? Can you share sample data?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @ILikeToCode I'm using statsmodels.formula.api.

Comment: @jakeChavis is your member total supposed to be an integer? Could you tell what T.1,001 is supposed to be? If it is 1.001, then first parse this string from [2:], change "," to "." and then use int(member_total).

Comment: @ILikeToCode T.1,001 is a categorical interpretation of one rows value for member total (1,001). So in my data, there is no T.1,001, just 1,001. It should be an integer, yes. I'm just not sure how to get it that way.

Comment: Can you show what it looks like in your df? I.e. type (df.member_total)

Comment: @ILikeToCode Yes, I've added the information above in the description.

Comment: @JakeCahavis is 27,908 supposed to be twenty seven thousand nine hundred and eight? Because of the ",", I think your system is reading what should have been a number as a string and therefore the type is object. Consider removing the , from the string and then cast it to int or float as required.

Comment: @ILikeToCode I tried to do what you just mentioned but it doesnt seem to work. See image "dropping comma" in the description. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @JakeChavis it seems you have not removed it. As you can see in your next cell the comma is still there which makes it not possible for pandas to change to int. Is your dataframe called sub? I think you should do sub.member_total = sub.member_total.replace(',',""). Try that?

Comment: Does `df['member_total'] = df['member_total'].astype(int)` given an error as well?

Comment: @ILikeToCode I received the following when I tried that.

"A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead"

Comment: @BeRT2me I received the following error when I tried that:

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '27,908'

Comment: What *are* `df['member_total']` exactly... what do `df['member_total'].loc[1]` and `type(df['member_total'].loc[1])` return?

Comment: @BeRT2me df['member_total'].loc[1] returns:

'20,434'

type(df['member_total'].loc[1]) returns:

str

Answer (score 1):

I realized you were just using the replace method incorrectly, when you want to modify a column, you have to identify the DataFrame that it's in as well. Yours appears to be called `sub`, with the column in question being `member_total`. ~ So, the correct way to use replace would be:

```
sub['member_total'] = sub['member_total'].replace(',', '')
```

or

```
sub['member_total'].replace(',', '', inplace=True)
```

---

To make everything you're trying to do one line:

```
sub['member_total'] = sub['member_total'].replace(',', '').astype(int)
```

---

If this *STILL* fails, a more robust method would be:

```
sub['member_total'] = sub['member_total'].replace('\D', '', regex=True).astype(int)
```

Comment: This is why we copy our outputs as text, rather than posting them as images that must  be clicked :')